# Make an extension is VSCode work only with specific languages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have recently installed an extension in VSCode that I find very useful for my workflow.

The extension is available at [This Repository](https://github.com/TaberIV/do...endMatch).
It lets you underline the beginning and ending syntax of code blocks, and I find it to be really useful for working in html.erb files since VSCode doesn't do a really good job at highlighting certain snippets of code.

Is there a way to make the extension work only in specific languages or specific file types?
Currently it works globally, even on plain text (for example if I type "do end" it will underline it even if I'm not in ruby language or in a `.rb` file). I would like it to work only in `.rb` and `.html.erb` files.

Let me explain it in a more technical way:

### Current behavior:

If I open a Plain Text file in VSCode and type `do end` the extension will underline it.

### Expected behavior:

If I open a Plain Text file in VSCode and type `do end` the extension d̲o̲e̲s̲ ̲n̲o̲t̲ have to underline it. It has to underline `do end` o̲n̲l̲y̲ in `.rb` and `.html.erb` files.

---

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Look at [language onActivation events](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events#onLanguage).

In your `package.json` file:

```
"activationEvents": [
  "onLanguage:ruby",
  "onLanguage: whatever the languageID for .html.erb files is"
]
```

Replace with your language identifiers for `.rb` and `.html.erb` files, you can have multiple `onLanguage` events as shown.

---

Also, looking at the extension's `package.json` link you provided, you should remove the `activationEvent` `"*"` - so only the above (I don't know what the language identifier for `.html.erb` files is).

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. The extension still underlines the blocks everywhere. Maybe there is something else in the extension that is not configured properly, I think I will live with it. Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: See some comments in the edited answer, particularly remove `"*"` as an activation event.

Comment: I tried to use only "onLanguage:ruby". At first I tried to see if the extension worked on a .html.erb file, and it didn't (which is good). Then I went on a .rb file, and it worked (again, good). But then I went back to the .html.erb file, and it started to work here too (bad). Then I checked on a Plain Text and it worked here too. To me it seems that the extension gets activated whenever I use Ruby, then it stays active globally. I think it is not programmed to work only on specific languages.